# Plug in eSATA hard drive after "Safely Remove Hardware" without restart

Tags: windows-7, esata

I have a SATA drive plugged into an eSATA port. I can use the option "Safely Remove Hardware" to remove the device, to which I then unplug it.

However if I plug the device back in without first restarting my computer, the drive won't appear to Windows (even under "Disk Management"). How can I get this hard drive to show back up without restarting my computer each time?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have tried some of this...

How quickly are you plugging the HD back in after "ejecting" it and unplugging it? Perhaps if you delay a bit, or even a long time before re-plugging the HD it may work.

After re-plugging the HD back in, how long do you wait before deciding it is not being recognized? Perhaps after waiting more time, it will be recognized.

If you have more than one eSata ports on your computer, try alternating which port you plug the HD back into.

If you have access to another eSata HD (even temporarily) you could try plugging in a different HD after removing yours, to see if it is recognized.

Open **`Control Panel`** and click **`Device Manager`**. Then locate your eSata controller/adapter, and right-click on it, and select ***`Scan for hardware changes`***.

Try the ***Hardware and Devices troubleshooter***. Perhaps it will re-establish connection to your drive: **Control Panel**-->**Troubleshooting**-->**Hardware and Sound**-->**Hardware and Devices**--><kbd>**Next**</kbd>